# NSUserDefaults or keychain is better to save username and password in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, keychain

In my iphone app there is some confidential data like username, password and some urls to a webservice. 
Which one is better NSUserdefaults or keychain.
Somebody says NSUserdefaults is insecure. Why it is insecure?
and can any one give the pros and cons of each one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

NSUserDefaults is quite easy to use and stores one value per key only. But apparently, it is not a very secure method, as there is no encryption.

But the Keychain is secure, though it is a bit hard to code.
You can refer these link to use keychain access.

http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code

you can also use this library deviced by Simon

https://github.com/goosoftware/GSKeychain

I hope it helps you!!

Comment: Simon's github library is here now: [https://github.com/sumanthk2006/GSKeychain](https://github.com/sumanthk2006/GSKeychain)

Answer (score 14):

It may be useful to notice that Keychain data will be persisted even if you app is deleted, but NSUserDefaults data will go away with the app (NSUserDefaults is part of the app sandbox, Keychain is an app-independent service).

Answer (score 7):

Anything stored in NSUserDefaults can be (relatively) easily opened and read, whether on the device or in a (non-encrypted) backup to iCloud or to a sync'd Mac.

[Keychain, on the other hand, is meant for stuff like certificates and passwords](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/01/05/using-keychain-to-store-passwords-ios-iphone-ipad/). I've linked an article titled "How Not To Store Passwords in iOS" which gives a bit more useful detail, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Keychain is way better solution,  because it is more secure, but anyway, if you would save this kind of information into the NSUserDefaults, your users wouldn't feel any different. If someone would hack their device, they could get information from Keychain, the same as they would get information from UserDefaults. So this question of security is rhetoric. But anyway, the good programming style is to save this data into the Keychain!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Keychains.
Using Keychain, you can store your password in encrypted form. Take a look at Apple's [GenericKeychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/index.html) sample.

NSUserDefaults is a little less secure when compared with Keychain.
In NSUserDefaults data can accessed easily if the specific key is known. This is not the case in Keychain.

**You can also convert NSUserDefaults to Keychains. Take a look** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869242/converting-nsuserdefaults-to-keychain).

Comment: *In NSUserDefaults data can accessed easily if the specific key is known. This is not the case in Keychain*. What do you mean by this?