# Login/Logout system for iPhone app

Tags: ios, xcode, session, core-data, authentication

What is the best way to keep a session on an iPhone app? I want something similar to this:

- when I Log in the app must store the person that name of the person
  that logged in

  - when I Log out that session will be destroyed without no possibility to enter the app beside logging in again
  - when the app is put in background the session must be kept
  - when the app closes the session must be destroyed and the user must log in again when he opens the app

How can I store the session on the phone and have this functionality's? The login is made using CoreData and the databases are stored on iCloud.

Comment: As I know NSUserDefaults will solve your problem . After login just store those values using NSUserDefaults and after logout clear those values from NSUserDefaults .

Comment: if the app closes will the User Defaults be deleted? I don't want the session to be kept if the app was closed

Comment: No , the session will be there . If you dont want to kept the session then why don't you take the variables in the appdelegate . So that once the app closes the variable will be reset .

Comment: I'll try using a delegate thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to user the `keychain` to store user name and password. 
You can use `NSUserDefaults` but it would not be secure. If you are using `NSUserDefaults` then store password in encrypted form.

`keychain` is more secure than `NSUserDefaults`.

[This Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525474/nsuserdefaults-or-keychain-is-better-to-save-username-and-password-in-iphone-app) may help you.