# Store secure values

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add an in game currency to my swift/spritekit game, you wont be able to buy it. It has not monetary value, so if people crack it, it wouldnt be the end of the world.

However I dont wanna make it too easy I.E. NSUserDefaults. Is there a way to do this more securely? game center? iCloud? not sure the protocol here.

Comment: What's the problem with using `NSUserDefaults`? On a non-jailbroken iOS device, the user has no way of accessing the user defaults. Even someone with a developer licence can only change them for their own apps.

Comment: If you really want to be "more secure" than vanilla `NSUserDefaults`, you could use `NSUserDefaults` with a benign key like `NotYourMoney` and then do a simple reversible hash to obscure it.

Comment: I read theres ways to get to it, even un-jailbroken. I think vanilla will be fine, just wanted to see if there was a standard way, that I was overlooking.

Comment: Put the value in some kind of class and archive it (in user defaults or as a file). Just my 2 cents ;)

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525474/nsuserdefaults-or-keychain-is-better-to-save-username-and-password-in-iphone-app