# swift: is userDefaults safe for storing username and password?

Tags: swift

my app gives the possibility to store username and password.
for now i do that using `UserDefaults.standard.set(pw,forKey: "password")`
Is this safe or should i use something else or encrypt the pw somehow?

Comment: I think NO. You can take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525474/nsuserdefaults-or-keychain-is-better-to-save-username-and-password-in-iphone-app

Comment: If a password needs to be stored use the keychain, that is what it is for.